# nested devise user's show path helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

I have nested my controller account which uses a devise user like

```
resources :venues do
    resources :accounts
end
```

In my accounts controller the index is

```
before_action :get_venue

  def index
    @venue
  end

def get_venue
      @venue = Venue.find(params[:venue_id])
    end
```

I have also tried my index controller as

```
  def index
    @venue.users.all
  end
```

I would like to show all the users/accounts for this venue in my view
<%= link_to 'Show Account', venue_accounts_path(user) %>

The generated URL is

```
/venues/2/accounts
```

and I would like it to be

```
/venue/1/accounts/1
```

Running rails routes I see

```
venue_account GET    /venues/:venue_id/accounts/:id(.:format)
     accounts#show
```

So I assumed that venue_accounts_path(user) will give me /accounts/1/user/1 but that is not what I get.

Answer (score 0):

found it

if it is a nested resource then the helper becomes

```
venue_account_path(@venue, user)
```

though I didn't find it in documentation here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources